# Resolve Button on Case Form - CRM 2015

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-2015

Resolve button and Cancel button on my Case form do not work. They just don't fire anything. As a system admin when I try to cancel a case or resolve a case, it works. But as a Business Admin (Read, Create, Update) I cannot Cancel or Resolve the case. There are javascripts being used on this form but none of them interact with security roles, users or the resolve and cancel buttons on the form. We also looked into the security roles for Business Admin but they have the appropriate security roles to cancel and resolve a case. The funny part is I was able to resolve a case using the resolve button whilst on the Active Cases View which makes me think it is not security related.

Please help!!

Comment: So while on the Active Cases View you are able to resolve, but not on the main page where you have much js running?

Comment: @JacobH That is correct.

Comment: Try troubleshooting steps like, 1) use a different browser to test if it is a compatibility issue 2) make a role with *full* rights to cases and related entities to rule out roles as an issue since you know the admin works 3) make a copy of the page with no js, test again

Comment: You have a broken JS somewhere, remove all customizations, make sure everything works, then put them back little by little to find out what's wrong

Comment: @Alex it works in another environment. Just not in Test. It works in Dev. We compared the javascript too but they are exactly the same including other processes.

Comment: Next step would be making sure the privileges and the data are correct. After that, firsthand debugging would be needed to provide a solution

Comment: Thanks for the response guys! It turns out that the issue was with security roles and privileges. We have fixed it by providing the correct privileges.

Comment: Can you share the exact privilege that was given to the role to solve the issue in answer?